# Update foreign keys to one column for all records in table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following query:

```
UPDATE D00EMA01.EMA_SUMO_CM_MEMBER sm
SET sm.SUBSCRIPTION_ID =
        (SELECT sb.SUBSCRIPTION_ID
         FROM D00EMA01.EMA_SUMO_SUBSCRIPTION_MIRROR sb
         WHERE sb.SUBSCRIPTION_NUMBER = sm.MEMBER_NUMBER);
```

It is a simple update statement where I want to update the sequence PK of table `EMA_SUMO_SUBSCRIPTION_MIRROR` to about 300k records in table `EMA_SUMO_CM_MEMBER`.

Currently this column is null for all records.

The query runs for a very long time, and eventually times out, and nothing seems to be happening with a large set of rows.

What is the more performant way to get the desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about `merge`?

```
merge into d00ema01.ema_sumo_cm_member sm
  using d00ema01.ema_sumo_subscription_mirror sb
  on (sb.subscription_number = sm.member_number)
  when matched then update set
    sm.subscription_id = sb.member_number;
```

Make sure `sb.subscription_number` and `sm.member_number` are indexed.

Comment: I will try this again with indexes properly set tomorrow. Currently the db is waiting, simple updates keep waiting infinitely. I don't have access rights to see blocking threads / users or unblock them, so shall revise tomorrow when it gets released. Btw yes I tried merge as well, but some problems that it takes forever. Maybe the indexes can solve the issue, or maybe it's just a problem with the db that ALL updates keep waiting forever. I don't know currently.

Comment: Does, by any chance, some other session keeps rows **locked** so your *update* has to wait until that other user either commits or rollbacks?

Comment: Doubtful, it's a preprod env where currently nobody is working as it's weekend. Unfortunately I don't have access to the vsession table.

Comment: The lock got released, this time the query ran swiftly without much trouble.

Comment: Excellent! I'm glad you made it.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use a sub query, it is very slow
In general, you can change and increase the time out for the execution of the query
When the time out expires and the query fails, all records return to their state before the query

Try this

```
UPDATE  sm
SET sm.SUBSCRIPTION_ID = sb.SUBSCRIPTION_ID
from D00EMA01.EMA_SUMO_CM_MEMBER sm 
inner join D00EMA01.EMA_SUMO_SUBSCRIPTION_MIRROR sb
on sb.SUBSCRIPTION_NUMBER = sm.MEMBER_NUMBER
```

Comment: The query executes fast. But I don't know why field SUBSCRIPTION_ID in table `EMA_SUMO_CM_MEMBER ` stays null for all the records (I executed the commit). When select-ing the condition, I get all the records, so that can't be the problem.. Any ideas?

Comment: maybe The column SUBSCRIPTION_ID  in the table  EMA_SUMO_SUBSCRIPTION_MIRROR  may also be empty!
Or maybe Trigger cancels the operation

Comment: Oracle [doesn't support](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/UPDATE.html#GUID-027A462D-379D-4E35-8611-410F3AC8FDA5) `update... from...`, so this code is not syntactically correct.